# Drawing colored balls without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An urn contains $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. $n$ balls are
>   drawn from the urn at random without replacement. If $k = 1, 2,
> > \ldots, n$, what is the probability that the $k$th draw will be black?
>
> Hint: Imagine the balls are numbered. What is the probability that
>   ball number $i$ will be drawn on the $k$th draw?

My attempt: Number the balls such that the first $b$ are black, and the last $w$ are white. There are $b+w \choose k$ ways to draw k balls without replacement. If we wish to draw ball $i$ on the $k$th draw, then there are $b+w-1 \choose k-1$ ways to draw the first $k$ balls. So $P($k th draw is black)=$\frac{b \cdot {b+w-1 \choose k-1}}{b+w \choose k}$

> Consider the same setting. What is the expected number of black balls
>   drawn in the $n$ draws?

My attempt: Let $E_i$ denote the event where exactly $i$ balls are drawn in the $n$ draws. Then $P(E_i) = \frac{{b \choose i} \cdot {w \choose n-i}}{b+w \choose n}$, so $$E(black balls)= \sum_{i=1}^{\min(b, n)}P(E_i)i =\sum_{i=1}^{\min(b, n)}\frac{{b \choose i} \cdot {w \choose n-i}}{b+w \choose n}i$$

Are my reasonings correct for these two problems?

Comment: The probability that the $k$th ball drawn is black is $\frac{b}{b+w}$

Comment: The balls are drawn without replacement

Comment: Correct. Why should the second or any subsequent draw be more or less likely to be a black ball than the first?

Comment: Pretty sure without replacement means whatever you drew before is going to affect what you are drawing next. You are thinking of with replacement

Comment: We don't know in advance what we will draw before the $k$th draw. If we consider both possibilities for the first ball, the probability that the second ball is black is $\frac{b}{b+w}\times\frac{b-1}{b+w-1}+\frac{w}{b+w}\times\frac{b}{b+w-1}=\frac{b}{b+w}$

Comment: The point of the hint is that each of the original balls is equally likely to be the $k$th ball drawn, with or without replacement. So the (unconditional) probability you want is $b/(b+w)$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained in the comments, the probability is independent of when the ball is drawn, and is simply $\frac b{b+w}$. The probability conditional on the results of the previous draws is different, but we don't know the results of the previous draws, so there's no reason to condition on them.