# Drawing Colored Balls without Replacement [Continued]

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

I recently saw a question which was left partially unanswered, and I thought it was interesting, but I also wasn't certain of the answer. The question is linked here: [Drawing colored balls without replacement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429231/drawing-colored-balls-without-replacement).

I am thinking specifically about the second part of the question, which asks: What is the expected number of black balls drawn in the $n$ draws?

Here are my thoughts:

I know we have a hypergeometric distribution of a random variable $X$ which takes parameters $n,b,w$, which represents the number of black balls selected when $n$ balls are randomly chosen from an urn that has $b+w$ balls in it, of which $b$ of them are black. So, we get a probability mass function of:

$$p(i)=\frac{{b\choose i}{w\choose n-i}}{b+w\choose n}$$

for $i=0,1,...,b$.

It seems, then, that the expectation of $X$ is just:

$$E(X)=np$$

where $p=\frac{b}{b+w}$.

Is this not the most accurate way of thinking about this? I tried to understand the OP's method, but I was left rather confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

\begin{align}
E[X]
&=\sum_{i=0}^{b+w}ip(i)
\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{b+w}i\frac{\binom{b}i\binom{w}{n-i}}{\binom{b+w}n}
\\&=\frac1{\binom{b+w}n}\sum_{i=0}^{b+w}i\binom{b}i\binom{w}{n-i}
\\&\stackrel{1}=\frac1{\binom{b+w}n}\sum_{i=0}^{b+w}b\binom{b-1}{i-1}\binom{w}{n-i}
\\&=\frac{b}{\binom{b+w}n}\sum_{i=0}^{b+w}\binom{b-1}{i-1}\binom{w}{n-i}
\\&\stackrel{2}=\frac{b}{\binom{b+w}n}\cdot \binom{b+w-1}{n-1}
\\&=\frac{b}{\frac{b+w}n\binom{b+w-1}{n-1}}\cdot \binom{b+w-1}{n-1}
\\&=n\cdot \frac{b}{b+w}
\end{align}
Notes:

1. Absorption identity: $k\binom{n}k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
2. Vandermonde's identity: $\binom{m+n}{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n}\binom{m}i\binom{n}{k-i}$.

#### Method 2

The probability a particular black ball is chosen is
$$
\frac{\binom{b+w-1}{n-1}}{\binom{b+w}n}=\frac{n}{b+w}
$$
By linearity of expectation, the expected number of black balls chosen is $b$ times this.